# How to add datepicker dynamically in bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to increment datepickers dynamically using jquery. Here if i click button with class name  addButton, the date picker are incremented but the date is not showing to select. This is because of id problem how to solve it.

```
<form id="taskForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Task(s)</label>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task[]"   placeholder="Task" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 dateContainer">
                    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dueDatePicker">
                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dueDate[]" placeholder="Due date" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- The template for adding new field -->
            <div class="form-group hide" id="taskTemplate">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task[]"
                        placeholder="Task" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 dateContainer">
                    <div class="input-group input-append date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> <input type="text"
                            class="form-control" name="dueDate[]" placeholder="Due date" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**script**

```
 .on('added.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            if (data.field === 'dueDate[]') {
                // The new due date field is just added
                // Create a new date picker
                data.element
                    .parent()
                    .datepicker({
                        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
                    })
                    .on('changeDate', function(evt) {
                        // Revalidate the date field
                        $('#taskForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', data.element);
                    });
            }
        })

        // Add button click handler
        .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
            var $template = $('#taskTemplate'),
                $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .insertBefore($template);

            // Add new fields
            // Note that we DO NOT need to pass the set of validators
            // because the new field has the same name with the original one
            // which its validators are already set
            $('#taskForm')
                .bootstrapValidator('addField', $clone.find('[name="task[]"]'))
                .bootstrapValidator('addField', $clone.find('[name="dueDate[]"]'))
        })
```

Comment: .on('added.field.fv', function(e, data) {  you are missing 'event'

Comment: hi TechBreak sorry for the inconvenice

Comment: this is code for that  i am not mentioned  $('#dueDatePicker')
        .datepicker({
         autoclose : true,
            format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(evt) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            $('#taskForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', $('#dueDatePicker').find('[name="dueDate[]"]'));
        });

Comment: But still I am not getting sir

Comment: Edit your question and add it there

Comment: ok thank u sir noted

Comment: But In the formavalidation its wroking but when i usesd boostrap validation  not possible sir